# Algorithm to divide up linked objects (like contiguous US states) by some metric?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Use case: consider the 50 US states on a map, with each state corresponding to some cost function (i.e., market size). Is there an algorithm (and ideal an R/Python package) that divides the 50 states into N groups such that the variation in the sum of the cost function in each group is minimized? The only constraint is that all states in each group are contiguous (i.e., they form one large mass / connected to each other)

Comment: Very likely NP-complete with an easy reduction to set partition or bin packing or knapsack or something. You can probably use one of the known heuristics for those - like dividing the states into groups in descending order of size, roughly - to get a good but not optimal result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if that takes into account the contiguous states constraint

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question with a smaller search space that might possibly be more tractable, or at least easier to code for. Given N groups, pick N states and call them roots. One way to divide states into groups is to say that the group associated with a root is the set of states closer to this root than to any other root.  To allow you to fine tune this a bit, have a constant K for each root, and divide up states according to the sum of the distance to the root and the constant K for that root.

Groups created in this way always consist of contiguous states, because if a state is in a group, all of the states on the shortest path from that state to the root of the group are also in that group. If one of them was not in that group, that state would have a shorter path to a different root, which means that the original state would also have a shorter path, via that intermediate state, to the different root, which is a contradiction.

This still isn't a tractable problem, but you call hill-climb on the constants to try and even out the allocations, and you can hill-climb on the choice of roots. If you hill-climb from multiple random starts, you can hope that you will get some decent answers, and you might hope to get an idea of how good your best answer seen so far is by looking at the other hilltops found - I would be optimistic if the best answer seen occurred multiple times.

Here follows some Java with comments trimmed due to limits on bodies

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class States
{
  /** Info held for State */
  private static class StateInfo
  {
    private final String m_name;
    /** abbreviation of state - drawn on graph */
    private final String m_abbreviation;
    private final double m_latitudeDegrees;
    private final double m_longitudeDegrees;
    private int m_currentX;
    private int m_currentY;
    /** 0-up number allocated and offset in ArrayList */
    private final int m_number;
    /** link to neighbouring states */
    private final ArrayList m_neighbours =
      new ArrayList();
    /** colour to print in. Modified when states are grouped */
    private Color m_color = Color.BLACK;
    /** weight when computing variance */
    private double m_weight = 1.0;
    public String toString()
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(m_abbreviation + " color " + m_color);
      return sb.toString();
    }
    public StateInfo(String name, String abbreviation,
      double latitudeDegrees, double longitudeDegrees, int number)
    {
      m_name = name;
      m_abbreviation = abbreviation;
      m_latitudeDegrees = latitudeDegrees;
      m_longitudeDegrees = longitudeDegrees;
      m_number = number;
    }
    public double getLatitudeDegrees()
    {
      return m_latitudeDegrees;
    }
    public double getLongitudeDegrees()
    {
      return m_longitudeDegrees;
    }
    public String getAbbreviation()
    {
      return m_abbreviation;
    }
    public void addNeighbour(StateInfo si)
    {
      m_neighbours.add(si);
    }
    public List getNeighbours()
    {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(m_neighbours);
    }
    public void setCurrentPos(int x, int y)
    {
      m_currentX = x;
      m_currentY = y;
    }
    public int getX()
    {
      return m_currentX;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
      return m_currentY;
    }
    public int getNumber()
    {
      return m_number;
    }
    public Color getColor()
    {
      return m_color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color newValue)
    {
      m_color = newValue;
    }
    public double getWeight()
    {
      return m_weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(double newValue)
    {
      m_weight = newValue;
    }
  }
  public static class StatePanel extends JPanel
  {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      Rectangle rect = getBounds();
      double minLat = Double.MAX_VALUE;
      double maxLat = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
      double minLon = Double.MAX_VALUE;
      double maxLon = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
      for (StateInfo si: m_stateInfo)
      {
        double lat = si.getLatitudeDegrees();
        double lon = si.getLongitudeDegrees();
        if (lat  maxLat)
        {
          maxLat = lat;
        }
        if (lon  maxLon)
        {
          maxLon = lon;
        }
      }
      int numStates = m_stateInfo.size();
      double gapAdd = 1.0 / (double)(numStates + 1);
      double gapFactor = (numStates - 1) / (double)(numStates + 1);
      for (StateInfo si: m_stateInfo)
      {
        double x = (si.getLongitudeDegrees() - minLon) / (maxLon - minLon);
        x = x * gapFactor + gapAdd;
        double y = (maxLat - si.getLatitudeDegrees()) / (maxLat - minLat);
        y = y * gapFactor + gapAdd;
        int xpos = (int)Math.round(rect.x + x * rect.width);
        int ypos = (int)Math.round(rect.y + y * rect.height);
        g.setColor(si.getColor());
        g.drawString(si.getAbbreviation(), xpos, ypos);
        si.setCurrentPos(xpos, ypos);
      }
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      for (StateInfo si: m_stateInfo)
      {
        int xp = si.getX();
        int yp = si.getY();
        for (StateInfo ti: si.getNeighbours())
        { 
          if (si.getNumber()  rows = new ArrayList();
        for (;;)
        {
          String line = br.readLine();
          if (line == null)
          {
            break;
          }
          int len = line.length();
          int l1 = len - 1;
          ArrayList cells = new ArrayList();
          StringBuilder currentCell = new StringBuilder();
          for (int i = 0; i = l1)
              {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unterminated quote in line " + line);
              }
              ch = line.charAt(++i);
              if (ch != '"')
              {
                currentCell.append(ch);
                continue;
              }
              if ((i >= l1) || (line.charAt(i + 1) != '"'))
              {
                break;
              }
              currentCell.append(ch);
              i++;
            }
          }
          if (len > 0)
          {
            cells.add(currentCell.toString());
          }
          String[] row = new String[cells.size()];
          row = cells.toArray(row);
          rows.add(row);
        }
        String[][] result = new String[rows.size()][];
        result = rows.toArray(result);
        return result;
      }
      finally
      {
        fr.close();
      }
    }
    /** Read locations of states and links between them from file */
    public void readLocations(String filename, String linkFile) throws Exception
    {
      // First two lines of file are
      // # State,Latitude,Longitude,Abbreviation,Population
      // Alabama,32.806671,-86.79113,AL,4.859
      // Population is in millions. File is result of hand-editing together info from web
      String[][] data = readCsv(new File(filename));
      m_stateInfo = new ArrayList();
      m_stateInfoByAbbreviation = new HashMap();
      int num = 0;
      for (String[] row: data)
      {
        if (row.length  rootOffsetByColor = new HashMap();
      for (int i = 0; i  reducedWeights[i])
          {
            reducedWeights[i] = reduced;
          }
        }
        if (secondBest  totalByColor = new HashMap();
      for (;;)
      {
        allocateViaDistance(m_roots, initialWeights, m_colors);
        double varianceHere = getVariance(totalByColor);
        double total = 0.0;
        for (Double d: totalByColor.values())
        {
          total += d.doubleValue();
        }
        double target = total / m_roots.length;
        minimumNecessary(m_roots, initialWeights, m_colors, decrease, increase);
        boolean improved = false;
        // Don't need to change weight[0] as we can regard everything else as
        // compared to that as a standard
        for (int i = 1; i  totalByColor)
    {
      totalByColor.clear();
      for (StateInfo si: m_stateInfo)
      {
        Color key = si.getColor();
        Double d = new Double(0.0);
        if (totalByColor.containsKey(key))
        {
          d = totalByColor.get(key);
        }
        totalByColor.put(key, new Double(d.doubleValue() + si.getWeight()));
      }
      int numUsed = totalByColor.size();
      if (numUsed  totalByColor = new HashMap();
      return getVariance(totalByColor);
    }
    public StateInfo getState(String abbreviation)
    {
      return m_stateInfoByAbbreviation.get(abbreviation);
    }
    public void setColorsRoots(Color[] colors, StateInfo[] roots)
    {
      m_roots = roots;
      m_colors = colors;
    }
    public StateInfo[] getRoots()
    {
      return m_roots;
    }
    public double climbRoots(double[] weights)
    {
      for (;;)
      {
        double current = getVariance();
        boolean improved = false;
        for (int i = 0; i  chosen = new HashSet();
        m_roots = new StateInfo[weights.length];
        for (int j = 0; j  m_stateInfo;
    private Map m_stateInfoByAbbreviation;
    private double[][] m_distances;
    private StateInfo[] m_roots;
    private Color[] m_colors;
  }
  /** compute all-pairs distances (Floyd - Warshall) */
  public static void allPairs(double[][] distances)
  {
    int pass = 0;
    for (boolean changed = true; changed;)
    {
      changed = false;
      System.err.println("Pass " + (pass++));
      for (int i = 0; i  totalByColor = new HashMap();
            var = sp.getVariance(totalByColor);
            System.out.println("Multiple start Climbed to variance " + var);
            System.out.println("Roots " + Arrays.toString(sp.getRoots()));
            System.out.println("Totals " + totalByColor.values());
          }
          System.out.println("Allocated result is " + sp.getVariance());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          System.err.println("Exception setting up: " + ex);
          ex.printStackTrace();
          return;
        }
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        w.setTitle("States");
        Container cp = w.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        w.pack();
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setVisible(true);
      }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's some example code of how you can generate all possible groups of states up to a reasonable number, trick is representing the ith state by two to the power of i. And a group of states is a 64 bit integer with bits corresponding to its states.

```
data = """AK    WA
AL  FL
AL  GA
AL  MS
AL  TN
AR  LA
AR  MO
AR  MS
AR  OK
AR  TN
AR  TX
AZ  CA
AZ  CO
AZ  NM
AZ  NV
AZ  UT
CA  HI
CA  NV
CA  OR
CO  KS
CO  NE
CO  NM
CO  OK
CO  UT
CO  WY
CT  MA
CT  NY
CT  RI
DC  MD
DC  VA
DE  MD
DE  NJ
DE  PA
FL  GA
GA  NC
GA  SC
GA  TN
IA  IL
IA  MN
IA  MO
IA  NE
IA  SD
IA  WI
ID  MT
ID  NV
ID  OR
ID  UT
ID  WA
ID  WY
IL  IN
IL  KY
IL  MO
IL  WI
IN  KY
IN  MI
IN  OH
KS  MO
KS  NE
KS  OK
KY  MO
KY  OH
KY  TN
KY  VA
KY  WV
LA  MS
LA  TX
MA  NH
MA  NY
MA  RI
MA  VT
MD  PA
MD  VA
MD  WV
ME  NH
MI  OH
MI  WI
MN  ND
MN  SD
MN  WI
MO  NE
MO  OK
MO  TN
MS  TN
MT  ND
MT  SD
MT  WY
NC  SC
NC  TN
NC  VA
ND  SD
NE  SD
NE  WY
NH  VT
NJ  NY
NJ  PA
NM  OK
NM  TX
NM  UT
NV  OR
NV  UT
NY  PA
NY  VT
OH  PA
OH  WV
OK  TX
OR  WA
PA  WV
SD  WY
TN  VA
UT  WY
VA  WV""".splitlines()

edges = [line.split() for line in data]
states = sorted(set([node for pair in edges for node in pair]))
state_map = {}
groups = [set() for _ in range(52)]
neighbours = [[] for _ in range(52)]
for i, state in enumerate(states):
    state_map[state] = i
    state_map[i] = state
    groups[1].add(1 << i)
for a, b in edges:
    i, j = state_map[a], state_map[b]
    neighbours[i].append(j)
    neighbours[j].append(i)

for group_size in range(2, 20):
    prev_groups = groups[group_size-1]
    print "group size: %d, count: %d" % (group_size - 1, len(prev_groups))
    current_groups = groups[group_size]
    for group in prev_groups:
        for i in range(51):
            state = 1 << i
            if state & group == 0:
                for j in neighbours[i]:
                    if group & (1 << j) > 0:
                        current_groups.add(group | (1<<i))
group size: 1, count: 51
group size: 2, count: 111
group size: 3, count: 323
group size: 4, count: 1063
group size: 5, count: 3714
group size: 6, count: 13219
group size: 7, count: 46858
group size: 8, count: 163360
group size: 9, count: 556059
group size: 10, count: 1838076
group size: 11, count: 5873753
group size: 12, count: 18076855
group size: 13, count: 53409207
```

Comment: this might be helpful too: https://github.com/ubikuity/List-of-neighboring-states-for-each-US-state/blob/master/neighbors-states.csv